# Promises with NodeJS

Tags: node.js, promise

I'd like to use promises with NodeJS but it seems not working as expected.

I'd like to see `LOG 1`, `LOG 2` and `LOG 3` for all files in this order. And `LOG 4` is hidden...

**But I get this :**

```
LOG 1
LOG 3
LOG 1
LOG 3
LOG 1
LOG 3
SUCCESS LOG 2
SUCCESS LOG 2
SUCCESS LOG 2
SUCCESS LOG 2
```

**My code :**

```
var filePromise = _.map(files, function(file) {

var filePath = './sql/' + file;

fs.lstat(filePath, function(err, stats) {

  if (stats.isFile() && file !== '.gitignore' && file !== 'index.js') {

    fs.readFile(filePath, 'utf-8', function(err, data) {

      console.log('LOG 1');

      db.query(data).then(function() {
        console.log(colors.green('SUCCESS LOG 2'));
      }).catch(function() {
        console.log(colors.red('ERROR LOG 2'));
      });

      console.log('LOG 3');

    });
  }
});
});

Promise.all(filePromise).then(function() {
  console.log(colors.green('LOG 4'));
});
```

Comment: Your database query us async call. It will skip that block and begins next execution. You can use async/await or place your code inside of the then block of the query

Comment: As @Sagar said, the execution does not pause at the `db.query` async call. Instead once the async action has been triggered, the main thread will jump to the next line and continue execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for `filePromise` to contain a collection of promises, you need to return a promise for each iteration of your map call. Only then will the call to `Promise.all` be evaluated correctly.

```
var filePromise = _.map(files, function(file) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var filePath = './sql/' + file;

        fs.lstat(filePath, function(err, stats) {

            if (stats.isFile() && file !== '.gitignore' && file !== 'index.js') {

                fs.readFile(filePath, 'utf-8', function(err, data) {

                    console.log('LOG 1');

                    db.query(data).then(function() {
                        console.log(colors.green('SUCCESS LOG 2'));
                        resolve();
                    }).catch(function() {
                        console.log(colors.red('ERROR LOG 2'));
                        reject();
                    });

                    console.log('LOG 3');

                });
            } else {
                reject(new Error("failed condition"))
            }
        });
    })
});

Promise.all(filePromise).then(function() {
    console.log(colors.green('LOG 4'));
});
```

This does not fix the ordering of your console logs. That is a separate issue. Your console logs are not actually out of order, they are logging as expected. However, this is due to the async call you are making to `db.query` which, when triggered does not block waiting for a response. Instead the next line is executed immediately after the function call returns.

**Side note:** Make sure to handle your `err` arguments passed to the inline callback functions of `fs.lstat` and `fs.readFile`. Failure to do so will result in the promise never completing in the event of an error.

Comment: @tonymx227 not sure I'd be swallowing the internal errors as displayed here (and in your original code), the errors should be propagated up the stack and handled elsewhere or at least be logged better inline.

Comment: @James I did state that in the "Side note" below the code.

Comment: @LukeStoward you did, but as a bare minimum to ensure your code works e.g. your code doesn't propagate the error from `db.query` so if that fails, the callstack is lost. Just emphasising the point to the OP that swallowing errors, in general, usually isn't a good idea.

Comment: @James Agree completely. I (perhaps wrongly) left the error handling logic out, since the example was already quite big. Hopefully, the OP read all of the solution and is handling errors.